# Why does chibi-scheme throw this error

Tags: scheme

I get an ERROR on line 11 of file project_euler.scm: empty application in source: () whenever I run this code below using chibi-scheme v 0.5.3 but it just runs fine when I use Dr Racket. Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

```
#! /usr/bin/env chibi-scheme

(define (sum-of-amicable-pairs n)
  (let ((sums (list->vector (map (lambda (i) 
                                   (reduce + 0 
                                           (filter (lambda (j) (= (remainder i j) 0)) 
                                                   (iota (+ 1 (quotient i 2)) 1 1)))) 
                                 (iota n 0 1)))))
    (let loop ((len (vector-length sums))
                    (res-list '())
                    (i 0))
      (cond
        ((= i len) (reduce + 0 res-list))
        ((and (< (vector-ref sums i) n) 
              (or (> (vector-ref sums i) i) (< (vector-ref sums i) i))
              (= (vector-ref sums (vector-ref sums i)) i))
         (loop len (cons (+ (vector-ref sums i) (vector-ref sums  (vector-ref sums i))) res-list)
               (+ i 1)))
        (else
          (loop len res-list (+ i 1)))))))

(sum-of-amicable-pairs 10000)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it doesn't handle empty quoted lists? Is there more information about the error than what you posted? DOES it handle quoted lists in general?

Comment: Okay, I downloaded Chibi-Scheme and it seems it does handle quoted lists properly. Can you link the rest of your code so that I can test it? Chibi doesn't come with some of the procedures you have like `iota` and neither does Racket.

Comment: thats all the code...it is a function to solve problem 21 of project euler.

Comment: to add, it happens when you try to use chibi scheme on the command line by passing it a filename to execute.

Comment: Try changing '() to (list) instead. That seems to "solve" the problem, but then it complains about `i` being undefined, which leads me to believe that it does not have lexical scope. I guess it does different things when it loads a file than when you use the REPL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I think I know what's going on here. When you load up the chibi-scheme REPL, it's using R7RS Scheme, but when you load a file, it's using the most basic version of Scheme that Chibi supports. See: http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/#h3_SchemeStandard

If you put `(import (scheme base))` at the top of your file then you no longer get the error about the empty application. Also you should do `(import (srfi 1))` in order to get the list processing procedures you use. See: http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/#h2_StandardModules